# jquery not properly executed in internet explorer 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have a page with header and footer div height set to 100px, and I made a simple jquery function that makes the central element change its height on browser resize, so that the page is always 100% of the viewport tall.

```
//resize
function resize_scroll_pane() { 
    var dynamic_height = $(window).height() - ($(".navbar").outerHeight() + $(".footer").outerHeight());
    $(".scroll-pane, .items, .items img").css("height",dynamic_height + "px");
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    resize_scroll_pane();
    $(window).bind('resize', resize_scroll_pane);
});
```

It works like a charm in all browsers except in IE8. Can anyone help me figure out why? I'm using jquery 1.11.1 which should be IE8 compatible, and I also included html5shiv.min.js and respond.min.js to expand IE8's functionality.

Comment: What does or doesn't it do in IE8?

Comment: I know this is not the answer you are after but stop supporting IE8 (only 2% of users use it: http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp). It is an old crapy browser and if anyone still uses it they deserve a crappy internet experience.

Comment: IE8 is not 2% of global users. This stats is only about W3Schools visitors (mostly web students and non-regarding professionals, so it makes sense that only 2% of this audience uses IE8). "From the statistics below (collected from W3Schools' log-files since 2002), you can read the long term trends of browser usage."

Comment: Does IE8 throw an error in its console ?

Comment: If you don't mind using IE9+, you may want to use `calc(100vh - 200px)`. Then you don't have to use jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(window).scroll(resize_scroll_pane);
$(window).resize(resize_scroll_pane);
```

you may use both of them. Its working for me in IE8.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems that the problem was caused by the jqueryLoader2 plugin which I initialized within the same $(document).ready(function() only didn't write its parameters in my example above to save space and because I didn't think it was relevant. I enclosed it within if (navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE 8/) == null) {} so it doesn't run in IE8 and now resizing works. I'm excepting your answer anyway because I decided to use your $(window).scroll(resize_scroll_pane); example.